# Python NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I was making a simple chatbot ai
Most of these codes are copied from others, so I don't know why the error is occurring.

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intents']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            global result
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result
```

I've tried deleting global, but then I get another error.
And I tried to rename the variable, but it still makes an error.
From what I searched, it seems to be a range-related problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

All I know is that there was an error in `return result`.

Comment: Think about what your function should return, if the condition `if i['tag'] == tag` is never met.

Comment: Solution: stop copying random code from other places and wonder why it does not work. Instead write code yourself that you do understand. Having globals is very often a very bad idea, particularly if you do not know what you are doing and how to build a somewhat clean application.

Comment: How will `result` be set if `list_of_intents` is empty or the condition is false?

Comment: `result` is not set to anything if the condition is not met or if the `for` loop doesn't iterate at least once, try setting it something outside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing all the code, but it look like

- `global result` has not been defined before calling the function
- you assignment `result = ...` is inside an `if`, and your code never gets there

So, you probably return a variable that hasn't really been defined

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that result is never set, if the condition is not met (e.g. the json is empty). There are multiple ways to do this correctly. None of them will involve a global variable.

### Set a default return value at the beginning:

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    result = None  # Default return value
    tag = intents_list[0]['intents']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result
```

### Have an else statement after your for-loop

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intents']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    else:
        result = None  # Default value to use, if for-loop was not broken
    return result
```

### Simply return the values

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intents']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            return random.choice(i['responses'])
    return None  # Return default value if nothing has been returned from inside the loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code shared used you could try something as follows:

```
if i['tag'] == tag:
    return random.choice(i['responses'])
else:
    pass
```

Handle the else part as required. Setting the result to a global variable will return a previously set value even if the condition is not met.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).